# Is there any good software to track and compare rides using my own computer

Tags: software, strava, performance-tracking

I like being able to see a record of my cycling in Strava, and compare rides with previous ones, see if I'm speed up or slowing down etc.

But I don't like the idea of a company creating a database of where millions of identified people go. It seems like a privacy problem.

Is there any good way to view a history of my cycling and calculate cumulative figures using my own computer rather than sending the data to someone else to analyse?

I can copy a GPX file record of each ride to my computer but I haven't seen anything that will let me view all the data together, rather than just one ride at a time.

Comment: You might try gis.stackexchange.com for bulk gpx import and analysis questions.

Comment: consider asking on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ as well - that's their reason for existing.

Comment: Thanks I considered that but posting the same question on multiple sites is strongly discouraged. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: I use rubiTrak 4 Pro on OS X. But since that's an Apple-only solution, I will not suggest it as an answer to your problem. Have you tried RideWithGPS? It also uses the cloud, but it seems much less Strava-y. I use Garmin, but they store all your data in the cloud, though I have the default upload privacy set to *not* share my rides publicly.

Comment: Yes it can be a privacy problem, but it can also have some good aspects [Strava](http://metro.strava.com/) also sells the data back to cities (anonymized) so that they can help to improve cycling infrastructure and safety.  Tracking the rides on your own computer means that the information about your rides will never make it back to the city.

Answer (score 1):

I use [IPbike](http://www.iforpowell.com/cms/index.php?page=ipbike) for Android. It has strava upload in case you want it but also gives you files in sensible formats by sensible means. It's got sensor integration but I use it with only GPS. You can give it a good try before you buy.

The author is no stranger to this site; despite being almost a neighbour of mine according to play store, I've no connection (except for having eventually bought the software)

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I've been using to log data, and then I've been uploading it to Strava. I may have wrongly ignored it because it's on my phone not my pc. I find the user interface a bit difficult to work with in IPbike.

Comment: I switched from CycleDroid to IPBike so I could use a heart rate meter.

Comment: I only use basic features so haven't had any trouble with the UI (or tried very hard to configure it). You can certainly manually save each ride as csv or gpx, I haven't looked at the internal ipp file format but it wouldn't surprise me if its fairly easy to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but as I was writing the question I saw [Golden Cheetah](http://www.goldencheetah.org/) mentioned in the question [Post race analysis of performance](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30255/post-race-analysis-of-performance/30260#30260).

Golden Cheetah is a free software application for Mac, Windows and Linux that looks like it does what I'm asking for here. I haven't tried it yet, can't say how it compares to Strava.

Comment: It's on Linux too, and is in the software repositories provided by the Debian and Ubuntu distributors. Installing now to try.